# How to open up 'Launcher Icon Creation Wizard' in eclipse(Android)?

Tags: android, eclipse, icons

This wizard appears when creating new android projects.

I would like to change the app icon of an android project. 
Editing my new-version icon image into different density manually is kinda inefficient, therefore I want to open this wizard in eclipse again.
How am I supposed to do it?

the image of the wizard:
[image]

Answer (score 75, accepted):

1. Right click on your project.
2. Select `New` and then `other`.
3. In the `type filter text` section type in `android icon set`.
4. Select `Android Icon Set` from the result and click on `Next`.
   You can create your launcher icon again there!

Answer (score 4):

***Icon creation wizard***

- Select your project
- Ctrl+n
- Android Icon Set